# Pyautogui compare two nearly identical images and return desired one

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, screenshot, pyautogui

How would you go about using image detection on two very similar images im trying to use the code below to find when the volume icon changes from full to low but the icon overall is very similar and code below is returning the icon regardless of whether its full or low, i've tried using confidence but doesn't seem to change anything i am wanting to detect when the low sound icon is active.

On the application these icons are in the same spot and change when you walk in objects eg bushes, etc

Images im talking about are below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6seP.jpg

[Low volume sound icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95hFh.png)

[High volume sound icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CQGm.png)

I've attempted changing my confidence as it finds wrong one at 0.78 but at 0.77 it just cant find anything.

```
sound_image = None
while (sound_image == None):
    try:
        print("Found img")
        sound_image = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.getcwd() + "\images\misc\low_sound.png", confidence=0.77)
    except:
        print("Failed to find img try again 10 seconds")
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: look up other answers relating to matchTemplate, snoop in my answers. most people use it absolutely wrong. and I'd guess "pyautogui" does too.

Comment: the one answering ~3 hours ago is unaware of why this happens. [it's due to pyautogui using a matching mode that's useless](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/b693ca9b2c964988a7e924a52f73e15db38511a8/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L223). you can solve this easily with OpenCV's matchTemplate and the right matching mode. -- pyautogui and pyscreeze contain some awful and unmaintained code, such as https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze/blob/b693ca9b2c964988a7e924a52f73e15db38511a8/pyscreeze/__init__.py#L307

Comment: Ill try check out OpenCV matchTemplate if you have any other ideas/suggestions for it i'd like to hear them, im pretty new to python so hoping i can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me the high volume icon is just the low volume one with an extra arc. So it's no surprise pyautogui finds the low volume icon when there is a high volume one, as the low volume icon is literally a part of the high volume one.

Thus, you will need some extra logic to differentiate between the two icons. You could do it like this (pseudocode):

```
find_high_volume_icon()
if (found_high_volume_icon):
    Great, it's the high volume one!
else:
    find_low_volume_icon()
    if (found_low_colume_icon):
        It has to be the low volume one, because we didn't find the high one earlier
    else:
        None of the icons were found, they are probably not on screen
```

Comment: Yeah i know that they are the same image and that its the arc that's my problem is regardless it will detect the image that i'm not wanting to detect so for instance even if i was wanting to detect both images at some point in for instance the example code above it would return low volume as high volume and vice versa.

Been trying to figure this out for a little while, im pretty new to python so im sure the solution is something semi-simple that im just unaware of.

Comment: @DragonTTK according to a commenter on your question this might be solved using a different opencv matching mode. Unfortunately he is too lazy to post an answer or even suggest the proper mode.

Comment: I managed to find a work around for my issue with something else entirely different from opencv thanks for trying to help though.